# Menu buttons wont move

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page header with big text then sub text beneath it positioned on the left side of the page and a cluster of buttons for a menu on the right side of the page that I can move around to a certain position, but right now I am unable to move the buttons. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<style>
.button1, .button2, .button3 {display:block;}
.row {
  padding: 10%;
}
.button-group {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin:-340px auto;
}

.button1 {
height: 25px;
width: 80px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 120px;
}

.button2 {
height: 25px;
width: 80px;
z-index: 1;
float: right;
top: 50px;
left: 180px;
}

.button3 {
height: 25px;
width: 80px;
z-index: -1;
float: right;
top: 50px;
left: 20px;
}
</style>
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;


}
tr.border_bottom td {
border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}

th, td {
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
border-top: 3px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
<style>
body {
background-color: darkblue;
}
</style>
<style>
h2 {
font-size: 20px;
}

p {
font-size: 14px;
}
</style>

<style>
body {
color: white;
}

h1 {
color: white;
}

p {
color: darkgrey;
}
</style>
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    a.nounderline {text-decoration: none; }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    a.nounderline {text-decoration: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div style="padding-left:60px">
    <h2 size="6" style="font-family:sans-serif"><b>Python Code</b> 
</h2>
    <p>Make use of this database of Python code to improve your current projects</p>
</div
<div class="row button-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary button2"><a 
href="/movielist">BUTTON 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary button2"><a 
href="/python_forum">BUTTON 2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary button3">BUTTON 3</button>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<table width="90%">
 {% for x in pythonforum:  %}
  <tr>
    <td width=20%> {{ x[2] }} </td>
    <td width=20%> {{ x[1] }} </td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

My main goal is to get a button group that looks like the one you will see on the following site: http://www.christopherkoehler.net/blog/.
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just update your code with some fixes. i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
body {
 background-color: darkblue;
 color: white;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}

a.nounderline {
 text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0;
}

p {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: darkgrey;
 margin: 0;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}
tr.border_bottom td {
 border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}

th, td {
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: left;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
 border-top: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding: 10px;
}

.nav-link {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.nav-link ul {
 background-color: #000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 3px;
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
}

.nav-link li a {
    color: #eee;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-link li + li a {
 border-left: 1px dotted #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h2 size="6" style="font-family:sans-serif"><b>Python Code</b></h2>
        <p>Make use of this database of Python code to improve your current projects</p>
    </div>
<div class="nav-link">
<ul>
<li><a href="/movielist">BUTTON 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/movielist">BUTTON 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/movielist">BUTTON 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<table width="90%">
 {% for x in pythonforum:  %}
  <tr>
    <td width=20%> {{ x[2] }} </td>
    <td width=20%> {{ x[1] }} </td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table><br/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to get this for weeks.

Comment: Hey for some reason i can't figure out how to move it left or right

Comment: Do you want to move your navigation from right to left?

Comment: down a bit and to the left a bit.

Comment: Can you share any screenshot? Thanks

Comment: http://ethankbdca.pythonanywhere.com/pythonforum here is the link for the site i am working on. if you compare that to the link i put at the beginning of my post and compare them. i am trying to get something like that. I can't figure out how to load screenshots onto my comments so thats why i am giving links.

Comment: Sorry but i'm still not getting what exactly you want.

Comment: I would like to move the buttons over to the left about 1/4 of an inch and down about 1 inch.

Comment: I think you just want to add extra padding to **left** and **right**. I just update the code. Thanks

Comment: I had tried something to that earlier and the problem is it just drags the black background to the buttons to the left or down/down depending on what part you change. I am not able to figure out why this code is being so stubborn

Comment: Never mind. I added margin-top: 200px; to .nav-link